# Get the same function for replace

Tags: javascript

I have two strings like these

```
var temp = 'xx-y1 xx-y2 xx-y3';
var temp1 = 'zz-y1 zz-y2 zz-y3';
```

I wanna replace all the words started with "xx-" and "zz-" pattern and for this purpose I do this.

```
temp.replace(/\bxx-\S+/g, '');
temp.replace(/\bzz-\S+/g, '');
```

now my question is how can I have a single function and just call it?

I try to test this but it doesn't work!!!

```
func = function(str, pattern) {
  return str.replace(RegExp('\b' + pattern + '\S+', 'g'), '');
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be v.replace(etc);? v is your parameter in to function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `\` when calling `RegExp` constructor.

```
function replace(where, what) {
    return where.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + what + '\\S+', 'g'), '');
}
```